# Php backslash issue wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am quite new on stack so be easy on me when it comes to making mistakes, I will try to fix If I have done anything wrong.

I am using a plugin but modified it quite a lot. I am at the stage where it takes a peice of text and converts it to the one I want

For example:

```
$cross_post_content = preg_replace('/<strong>/', '[b]', $cross_post_content);
$cross_post_content = preg_replace('/<strong>/', '[/b]', $cross_post_content);
```

This line will replace This line will replace[CODE]  to [b][/CODE]

```
$cross_post_content = preg_replace('/<strong>/', '[b]', $cross_post_content);
```

The problem is to undo strong it is

```
</strong>
```

but it give me issue, maybe because it uses backslash, can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular expressions, / has a special meaning, literally you are terminating the regular expression after the third character.  In order to get around that, you have to cancel it out using a backslash, like so

```
$cross_post_content = preg_replace('/<\/strong>/', '[/b]', $cross_post_content);
```

For more information about preg_replace, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php.  For regex help itself see http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php